# Froala Editor get Current instance

Tags: javascript, jquery, froala

I am using Froala Editor on my website and I am stuck at the point of finding the correct way to get the current editor instance.

[Froala](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor)

My page has multiple editors which I have initialized using the class of the text area. Here is a sample page http://1minutewebsites.com/froala.php

On this page we can see two editors and when we see the page source we can see how I have initialized them.
In the `toolbars` I have added a `custom drop down` which we can see at the last, using [custom dropdown](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/examples/custom-dropdown).

Since there are two editors on the sample page, I want to click on the first editor and from the custom drop down select any one value. It inserts a short code in both the editors.

I want insert the short code only in the editor for which we are clicking on the drop down to insert the short code.

I have also added the script which can be viewed on the page itself. 
How can I insert the short code in the current editor instance ?

Comment: what happens if you have each edit with a different `id` and you initialize them separately? You can have the custom configs saved in a variable and pass them to both. `$('#editor1').editable(config) ;$('#editor2').editable(config);`

Comment: I cannot use the id as the page can have hundreds of editors which are added dynamically.

Comment: what about `$('textarea.editor_here').each(function (){ $(this).editable(config) } );`

Comment: I tried that it is not working. In that case I get error, e is undefined.

Comment: I made a little change to your script and got that working. If you can just create a answer I will mark that as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over all editors individually and initialize them. I also realized that your custom functions are set to insert to all of the editors.

You can initialize all of your editors by doing the following:

```js
var editorConfig = {};

$('textarea.editor_here').each(function (){ 
  $(this).editable(editorConfig) 
});
```

Also inside your current config, your custom dropdowns should be

```
'~vil~': function(element){
  this.insertHTML('~vil~');
}
```